# SELinux, Nginx and fcgiWrap: how to allow access to fcgiWrap socket?

Tags: nginx, selinux, socket, cgi

I am under Fedora 31 (linux kernel 5.4.13, Nginx 1.16.1, fcgiwrap 1.1.0) running with SELinux in enforcing mode (policy: targeted 3.14.4-44.fc31).

My box hosts a server driven by Nginx. Part of it relies on Perl scripts. Nginx has been configured to hand over CGI execution trough FastCGI with fcgiwrap (connection through a Unix socket /var/run/fcgiwrap/fcgiwrap@0.sock).

Everything has been tested in "Permissive" mode. Then it was switched to "Enforcing" mode. I received a bunch of AVCs which could be handled either changing booleans or creating custom policies as suggested by the audit comments.

However, one AVC cannot be addressed. Journal tells:

```
 type=AVC msg=audit(1580046727.459:548): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=4619 comm="nginx" path="/run/fcgiwrap/fcgiwrap-0.sock" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
```

Custom policy contains the following:

```
module nginx 1.0;

require {
    type httpd_t;
    type soundd_port_t;
    type http_port_t;
    type tor_port_t;
    type unconfined_service_t;
    type httpd_user_content_t;
    class tcp_socket { name_bind name_connect };
    class file { getattr read };
    class unix_stream_socket connectto;
}

#============= httpd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_t http_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_t httpd_user_content_t:file { getattr read };
allow httpd_t soundd_port_t:tcp_socket name_bind;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_t tor_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
allow httpd_t unconfined_service_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

As can be seen from the auto-generated comments, this custom policy has no effect because it is already included in the global policy.

After I add this module, nothing changes. I still receive AVC alerts suggesting the same fix.

If I revert to "Permissive" or if I set domain *httpd* in permissive mode, the CGI scripts are executed and I receive the expected output.

`ls -Z /var/run/fcgiwrap/fcgiwrap-0.sock` returns:

```
system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0 /var/run/fcgiwrap/fcgiwrap-0.sock
```

I was not able to find where label `httpd_var_run_t` was used and whether a boolean controlled access to this file type (I'm quite a newbie in SELinux configuration).

**How can I grant access to the socket in "Enforcing" mode?**

**EDIT 2020-01-27**

It looks like there is already a transition rule in module *apache* for:

```
allow httpd_t unconfined_service_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

but it is ineffective or another module (which one?) is blocking it. The temporary workaround is to put domain *httpd* in permissive mode, but I don't like it because any web server is now allowed to do anything.

Any idea why transition is denied?

Answer (score 0):

I've not checked or tested this adequately -- in fact I'm pretty sure this alone wont work.

I'm assuming that creation of the path `/var/run/fcgiwrap` has the directory type `unconfined_service_t` and I'm not certain if that is actually the case.

However this should get you somewhere started.

```
policy_module(nginx_local, 31.0.0)

require {
  type httpd_t;
  type unconfined_service_t;
}

stream_connect_pattern(httpd_t, unconfined_service_t, unconfined_service_t, unconfined_service_t)
```

As for the networking issues, you might just want to switch on the boolean `httpd_can_network_connect` which should silence a few of those already. Unless you're looking to be specific about it.

In the best and ideal circumstances it would be ideal to make a policy specific for your fcgi proces but thats a much more difficult undertaking, so getting nginx to just interact with unconfined services - whilst less secure - is a lot easier.

Comment: `http_can_network_connect` is already "on". Directory `/var/run/fgcwrap` has the same label as the socket irself. This is set by the general labeling policy. What is `stream_connect_pattern`? It is not suggested by `audit2allow`. Will it address my `connectto` denial?